# How to add renting times for an Item in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently making a renting system in which I need to create a time for when to rent and when to return the rented item using RoR. The code I have saves the time in the database and then rollbacks with the error `value required 2, got nil`.

Following is my code:

`AcquiretimesController < ApplicationController`

```
def create

    @item = Item.find(params[:item_id])

    @acquiretime = @item.acquiretimes.create(time_params)

    if @acquiretime.valid?
        flash[:success] = "You have successfully rented the item"
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        flash[:alert] = "Woops! Looks like there has been error. Please enter valid data."
        redirect_to root_path
    end
end

private

def time_params
    params.require(:acquiretime).permit(:required_time, :return_time)
end
```

For my view, I have used following:

```
<%= simple_form_for [current_item, @acquiretime] do |f| %>
    <div class = "add_item_form">            
        <%= f.input :required_time, as: :date, html5: true %>
        <%= f.input :return_time, as: :date, html5: true  %>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <%= f.submit 'Add Item', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

My model for Acquiretime is:

`class Acquiretime < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :item
    belongs_to :users
    validates :required_time, :return_time, presence: true
end`

For items,

`class Item < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :acquiretimes
end`

And the user,

`class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :items
  has_one :acquiretime
end`

Following is my error message in console:

> Started POST "/items/3/acquiretimes" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-01-07 18:28:04 +0545
>   Processing by AcquiretimesController#create as HTML
>     Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Zo9qj1VsLlMwgwSozATh2C//tMQHbFOaMvZ1IddeVdQxG7enNDmPWe64RO/1CmmpBlevmSfJ7/w9Fzey5NxP8A==", "acquiretime"=>{"required_time"=>"2018-01-07", "return_time"=>"2018-01-22"}, "commit"=>"Add Item", "item_id"=>"3"}
>     Item Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "items".* FROM "items" WHERE "items"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
>      (0.2ms)  BEGIN
>      (0.2ms)  COMMIT
>      (0.1ms)  BEGIN
>      (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
>   Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 117ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
>
> ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 2)):
>   app/controllers/acquiretimes_controller.rb:18:in `create'
>     Rendering /home/skj/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout
>     Rendering /home/skj/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
>     Rendered /home/skj/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb (5.7ms)
>     Rendering /home/skj/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
>     Rendered /home/skj/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.7ms)
>     Rendering /home/skj/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
>     Rendered /home/skj/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (2.7ms)
>     Rendered /home/skj/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (107.9ms)

Comment: Can you post the console output when the rollback occurs?

Comment: @kuwantum, I have added the error, please have a look at it

Comment: app/controllers/acquiretimes_controller.rb (line 18) - 

What is on that line? Seems the issue is there

Comment: That's the alert message part

Comment: Can you post your model code (Aquiretime I suppose)?

Comment: Try create with bang, `@item.acquiretimes.create!  time_params`, it will give you more meaningful error messages. Plus parse your time correctly using `Time.zone.parse('2018-01-07').to_time.iso8601`

Comment: @TheMouseMan I used bang, and it is now giving me error that `Validation failed: Users must exist` with the error in `@acquiretime = @item.acquiretimes.create!(time_params)`

Comment: So have you provided the `user_id` in `time_params`? Since your `Acquiretime` `belongs_to :user`, `Rails 5` won't accept it unless your provide user reference. P.S. it needs to be singular when you do `belongs_to` fix they typo in your `Acquiretime`

Comment: @TheMouseMan, thanks, it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @TheMouseMan in the reply section above, the problem has been solved. What I had problem was typo mistake in Acquiretime.rb where I have written `belongs_to :users` but should have been `belongs_to :user`.
Next is passing user.id from the form using the hidden_field:
`<%= f.hiddent_field :user_id, value: current_user.id%>`